# No me funcionan los filtros en Primefaces

Tags: datatables, primefaces

Tengo el siguiente archivo xhtml de Primefaces y no me está funcionando el filtro en el campo Pedido.

Que puede ser?

```html
<h:form id="form1">
             <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />
            <p:panel id="cabecera">
               
                   <h:outputText value="Normales : #{tblMaestro.tbl.con_prioridad_normal} - " style="font-size: 12px;font-style: oblique" />
                   <h:outputText value="Prioritarios : #{tblMaestro.tbl.con_prioridad_prioritario}" style="font-size: 12px;font-style: oblique" /> 
                  
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   <br></br> <br></br>
                  <h:outputText value="Ingresar la ubicación : " />
                   <p:selectOneMenu id="Ubicacion" value="#{tblMaestro.vusuario}" style="width:125px">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Todos" itemValue="sa" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Hogar" itemValue="directorLogisHogar" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Moda infantil" itemValue="DirectorLogisModaInf" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Bebes" itemValue="SuperBodBebe" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Hobbies" itemValue="SuperBodHobbies" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Todos LV" itemValue="DirectorLogisticoLV" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                  <p:spacer width="30" height="10" />
                 <p:commandButton  value="Filtrar"  update="tablero,cabecera"  action="#{tblMaestro.SetFilter()}"
                                   style="background:beige;"
                                   styleClass="colorButton"/>
                
            </p:panel>
             
             
             
             
             
             
             <p:dataTable id="tablero" var="dat" widgetVar="datTable" value="#{tblMaestro.pageData}" filteredValue="#{tblMaestro.filterData}" 
                          paginator="true" rows="20"
                          paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                         rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,20,50,100"
                          >
                
                 <p:column sortBy="#{dat.prioridad}"  headerText="Prioridad" style="width: 80px;font-size: 14px;#{dat.alarmaPrioridad?'background: yellow;':''}" styleClass="#{dat.alarmaPrioridad?'green;':''}">                    
                     <h:outputText value="#{dat.prioridad}"  />
                </p:column>
                
                 <p:column sortBy="#{dat.fecha}" headerText="Fecha" style="width: 120px;font-size: 14px;text-align: center">
                      <h:outputText value="#{dat.fecha}" />
                </p:column>
                
                   <p:column sortBy="#{dat.descripcionUltimoEstado}" headerText="Último Estado" style="width: 80px;font-size: 14px"  >
                       <h:outputText value="#{dat.descripcionUltimoEstado}"  />
                </p:column>
                
                   <p:column sortBy="#{dat.fechaUltimoEstado}" headerText="Fecha último estado" style="width: 80px;font-size: 14px"  >
                       <h:outputText value="#{dat.fechaUltimoEstado}"  />
                </p:column>
                 
                

                <p:column sortBy="#{dat.categoria}" headerText="Categoria" style="width: 80px;font-size: 14px;text-align: center;">
                    <h:outputText value="#{dat.categoria}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column sortBy="#{dat.cliente}" headerText="Cliente" style="width: 120px;font-size: 14px;text-align: center;">
                    <h:outputText value="#{dat.cliente}" />
                </p:column>

                  <p:column sortBy="#{dat.pedido}" headerText="Pedido" filterBy="#{dat.pedido}" filterMatchMode="contains"  style="width: 60px;font-size: 14px;text-align: center;">                      
                      <p:commandButton value="#{dat.pedido}" action="#{tblMaestro.OpenDetail(dat.pedido)}" update="form1:tblDetalle" onclick="PF('dlgDetail').show();"/>
                </p:column>

                  <p:column sortBy="#{dat.numero_oc}" headerText="Orden de Compra" style="width: 70px;font-size: 14px;text-align: right;">
                      <h:outputText value="#{dat.numero_oc}" style="text-align: right;"/>
                </p:column>
                
                           
                <p:column sortBy="#{dat.fechaVence}" headerText="Fecha vencimiento"  style="width: 120px;font-size: 14px;text-align: center;background: #{dat.alarmaVence}">                                      
                     <h:outputText value="#{dat.fechaVence}" />            
                </p:column>


                 <p:column sortBy="#{dat.unidades}" headerText="Unidades" style="width: 35px;font-size: 14px;text-align: center;">
                     <h:outputText value="#{dat.unidades}" />
                </p:column>

                 <p:column sortBy="#{dat.vendedor}" headerText="Vendedor" style="width: 120px;font-size: 14px;text-align: center;">
                     <h:outputText value="#{dat.vendedor}" />
                </p:column>
                 
            </p:dataTable>
       
             
             
             
             <p:dialog id="detalle" widgetVar="dlgDetail" modal="true"  height="500" width="800" position="top top">
                 
                 <p:dataTable id="tblDetalle" var="det" widgetVar="detTable" value="#{tblMaestro.detailData}">
                 <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText id="txtPedido" value="Pedido : #{tblMaestro.numPedido}"/>
                </f:facet>
                     
                     <p:column headerText="Estado" style="width: 35px;font-size: 14px;text-align: center;">
                         <h:outputText value="#{det.estado}" />
                       </p:column>

                     <p:column headerText="Fecha inicial" style="width: 35px;font-size: 14px;text-align: center;">
                         <h:outputText value="#{det.fechaInicial}" />
                    </p:column>

                     
                     <p:column  headerText="Hora inicial" style="width: 35px;font-size: 14px;text-align: center;">
                         <h:outputText value="#{det.horaInicial}" />
                    </p:column>

                 
                      <p:column  headerText="Usuario" style="width: 35px;font-size: 14px;text-align: center;">
                          <h:outputText value="#{det.usuario}" />
                    </p:column>    
                 </p:dataTable>           
             </p:dialog>
           
             
             
             
                   <br></br>
        Código colores
        <table border="1" style="width:25%">
                    <tr>
                       <th style="width:10px">Color</th>
                      <th style="width:10px">Tiempo Días</th>                       
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="background-color: lightgreen"></td>
                      <td style="width:10px">mayor a 8</td>                       
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="background-color: yellow"></td>
                      <td style="width:10px">Entre 8 y 3</td>                       
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                      <td style="background-color: orange"></td>
                      <td style="width:10px">Entre 4 y 3</td>                       
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="background-color: lightcoral"></td>
                      <td style="width:10px">Entre 2 y 0</td>                       
                    </tr>
                 
                  </table> 
        
        
             
             
             
             
             <p:ajaxStatus onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()" onsuccess="PF('statusDialog').hide()"  />
             <p:dialog  widgetVar="statusDialog" modal="true" draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false" showHeader="false">
                <p:graphicImage name="/images/loading.gif" />
                <p align="left"> Haciendo la consulta a la base de datos</p>
                 Por favor espere...
            </p:dialog>
             
             
    </h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione, publico la respuesta para las personas que tengan el mismo problema.

El problema esta en que se declararon los objetos de informacion del dataTable como tipo Vector, al cambiarlos al tipo List comenzó a funcionar

```
private  Vector<Registro> PageData; // master 
private  Vector<Registro> filterData; // Filtro
private  Vector<com.stilo.detalle.Registro> DetailData; // vector del detalle
```

Se cambio por :

```
private  List<Registro> PageData; // master 
private  List<Registro> filterData; // Filtro
private  Vector<com.stilo.detalle.Registro> DetailData; // vector del detalle
```